# Rails 3.1 Asset Pipeline doesn't work for me

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

I'm upgrading a Rails 2.5 app to Rails 3.1 rc4 and I'm getting tons of these kind of errors in development, related to the asset pipeline:

```
cache: [GET /assets/application-272985f6b5b17a3aeb1b84a6a376e225.css] miss, store
2011-07-06 16:03:56 +0300: Read error: #<NoMethodError: You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.each>
gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rack-1.3.0/lib/rack/handler/mongrel.rb:90:in `process'
gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/mongrel-1.2.0.pre2/lib/mongrel.rb:165:in `block in process_client'
gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/mongrel-1.2.0.pre2/lib/mongrel.rb:164:in `each'
gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/mongrel-1.2.0.pre2/lib/mongrel.rb:164:in `process_client'
gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/mongrel-1.2.0.pre2/lib/mongrel.rb:291:in `block (2 levels) in run'
```

Basically here the request for the application.css returns an empty body.

First I thought it might be a server issue, so I switched to webrick, but that didn't help.

Help is much appreciated. ;-)

Nico

Comment: I assume you put the css into the new directory-structure of rails? They should be in app/assets/stylesheets

Answer (score 5):

I met the same error. But the cause was that I set cache store to redis but I forgot to start redis server.

Comment: I had set my cache store to memcache and forgot to start it!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, not sure what the problem was, but I got rid of the issue by switching to thin as a webserver. The problem occurred with both webrick and mongrel.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error, because change the default memcached store to dalli.

see https://gist.github.com/1625476